# Exporting a tensor

Tags: export, tensors

I have a complicated and large tensor what can be shown in the simplest form as follows

[image]

How can I export it in this form?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "export it *in this form*". If you just want to export higher dimensional numerical arrays for interchange with other systems (or archival), take a look at the HDF5 format.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, I mean that I don't want that Mathematica flattens this tensor to a matrix (namely reduces its degree), rather I want to export it in a way so that when I import it in a new file, it gives me a tensor just like above, without any additional task.

Comment: @NSR Do you want to use the exported file with any other software or do you merely want to save a backup of the tensor in order to `Import` it later with _Mathematica_? For the latter, you can simply `Export` into _Mathematica_'s MX-format.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Thanks, In fact, I want to prevent from re-evaluating some integrals, so I export this final tensor and import it in my friends' Mathematica (in another system) in order debug other parts of my code. I have heard that MX-format can't be read in another system

Comment: "I have heard that MX-format can't be read in another system." That's true but it s worth a try as it would be the easiest and fastest way to do that.

Comment: In that case, for short-term storage, to be read back into the same Mathematica: use MX. For long term storage or exchange with other programs: HDF5.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher Ok. Thanks

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks again, can you give me a sample code (preferably for above tensor) for HDF5?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? There are many examples.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK.Thanks

Comment: @Henrik Not sure when DumpSave changed, but at least as of 11.3 .mx files can be read on different operating systems as long as `$SystemWordLength` is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just export as plain text; say your tensor is called `A`, the following will save it as a text file in the same directory as your notebook:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["tensor.txt", A];
```

You can import it later using

```
A = Import["tensor.txt"];
```

Comment: When looping through text fuiles then I'd rather prefer `Export["tensor.m", A];` and
`Import["tensor.m"];`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Thanks a lot. I checked using m-format and it worked but I'm worried about importing it to my friend's computer!

Comment: @NSR as long as you place the file in the notebook's directory on your friend's computer and do `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` in their notebook it should be fine.

Comment: @NSE The M-format won't make any problems because it is a pure text format hat can be read by every _Mathematica_ distribution. But because it is a text format, it is not as well compressed as the MX format (which is a binary format). So if you are about mover around large tensors, MX might od HDF5 might be better alternatives.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Ok, many thanks for your useful explanation

Comment: @Julius Thanks a lot. Good hint